# Why are exceptions so popular in C#/.NET programming compared to error codes in C++/Win32?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, exception, error-handling

I am someone migrating from a C++/Win32 development environment to C#/.NET. One thing that I have noticed is that mostly erroneous states are handled in C++/Win32 by the use of error codes and their propagation.

To the contrary most erroneous states in C# /.NET seem to be handled by the use of exceptions and error codes are seldom advised to be used.

Why so?

Comment: Have a look [Exceptions vs Traditional Error Handling Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab.aspx#exceptions_vs_traditional_errorhandling_methods)

Comment: Exceptions can provide a lot more information about what went wrong. Also, the `try-catch` statements make cleaner code. Your errors are handled below the functioning code.. instead of polluting it with checks for error codes.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I kind of disagree with your comment. You make it sound like a try-catch means that you shouldn't try to handle a problem in a block of code before an exception is thrown in the first place.

Comment: @HaemEternal If something isn't exceptional.. you wouldn't use an exception.. and therefore would check it at the source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main issue with error codes is that one needs to check them. Always.

And we are only human and can forget.

This can mean we can get our programs into inconsistent state by simply forgetting to check an error code.

If we forget to handle an exception, though, our program will exit.

This is seen as preferable to it continuing to run in an inconsistent state.

Much of the reason that error codes are still prevalent in C/C++ code is historical - these languages didn't have exception handling, so needed error codes. And there are many libraries and code out there that conforms to this idiom, so programmers need to keep with it.

There are other reasons to use exception apart from the fact that they cannot be ignored - they carry quite a lot of context, as [Marc observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214036/why-are-exceptions-so-popular-in-c-net-programming-compared-to-error-codes-in/14214118#comment19712396_14214118) - stack traces, messages and more, beyond the *type* of the exception.

Comment: Also I would add: the extra context. `InnerException`, `StackTrace`, etc - all invaluable when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

One of the major reasons I'd say is that error codes are platform specific. .NET was originally designed to be portable.

For example a `FileNotFoundException` is more universal than some obscure number that may vary depending on what platform you are running on.

Comment: The error codes are usually fairly well defined ... http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html

Comment: It's much worse when you call third-party libraries that return error codes. If a function returns an error code, and that function calls third party functions that can return overlapping ranges of error codes, you end up having to translate the error codes to the ones that the function should return (otherwise the codes will be ambiguous). You also end up having to maintain a master-list of error codes somewhere.

Comment: That's bogus. If you can define an exception class that is the same on all platforms, you can do so with error codes.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Funny.. that's what the BCL does because the WinAPI returns error codes. They have huge switch statements in the BCL that convert error codes to exceptions..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's very true. I'm with Marc on the extra's exceptions provide though like stack trace and layered exceptions.